# Asynchronous Destruction and RAII in C++

Tags: c++, asynchronous, raii

According to RAII when I destroy the object, its resources are deallocated. But what if the destruction of the object requires asynchronous operations?
Without using RAII I can call `close` method of my class that will call necessary async operations and will keep `shared_ptr` to my object (using `shared_from_this`) in order to gracefully process callbacks from the async operations. After calling `close` I can remove my pointer to the object since I do not need it anymore - but I know that the object will not be removed until the async operations are executed.

But how can I achieve this using RAII? One of the possible solutions can be using a wrapper that when destructed will call `close` method of by object. But.. will it mean that my classes are RAII classes?

```
class Resource: public std::enable_shared_from_this<Resource> {
    int id;
public:
close() {
    some_async_functin([t = shared_from_this()] {
        std::cout << "Now I am closed " << t->id << std::endl;
    }
}



}
```

My solution:

```
class ResourceWrapper {
   std::shared_ptr<Resource> res;

   ~ResourceWrapper() {
       res.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not just call `close()` from your destructor?

Comment: `But what if the destruction of the object requires asynchronous operations?` ? What if? Do it anyway. Decide if you want to synchronize or not. `how can I achieve this using RAII? One of the possible solutions can be using a wrapper that when destructed will call close method of by object.` Yes. `that my classes are RAII classes?` What are "RAII classes"? There is no _specific_ problem you are describing, only vague terms of "some object". Can you post an actual, real code of the problem you are solving?

Comment: with RAII you can still call close. see what `std::fstream` does.

Comment: and you can synchronize the destructor, like what `std::async`'s return value does.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I can not call close in the destructor because close should be called before the destruction - I need to handle the callbacks from async operations

Comment: @KamilCuk I have posted. I want async destruction - there is no necessity for me to wait untill the closure of the object but I want my class to correspond to RAII standard - it should not require calling open/close but just use constructor and destructor instead

Comment: @appleapple I do not need the synchronization of destructor - it is ok for me not to wait untill all async operations are performed. But using close instead of deallocation on destructor seems to be non-RAII

Comment: @КириллВолков wait or no wait, both fine as long as you're sure, it has nothing to do with RAII.

Comment: @КириллВолков note that as long as you already inside destructor, `share_from_this` would not stop the destruction (it'd probably not work anyway).

Comment: @KamilCuk
Actually now everything is performed using boost::io_context: after calling close, I can remove my own pointer to this object and fully forget about it. But when the closing operations are performed the callback will be called (so technically its the same thread).

Comment: @KamilCuk the question is whether my solution (I have added its implemetaion) is really the solution that corresponds to RAII

Comment: @appleapple yes, sure I understand that it is useless to call shared_from_this in destructor :) That's why I am searching the way to find a RAII implementation that will allow async closing. I have mosted my proposed solution

Comment: @KamilCuk Some of your comments have disappered

Comment: Look at `std::shared_ptr` for inspiration. There too the release of the resource and the current variable going out of scope are separated. Of course this is slightly different case, but similar idea, the resource can outlive the variable going out of scope.

Comment: @КириллВолков yes your current solution works (as long as you're sure not leave the program before it complete). I don't see what's your question though. (btw, you can simply copy id, so I don't see why you need the `class Resource` either)

Comment: @appleapple id is just an example :) The question was whether such an architecture is RAII

Comment: @КириллВолков well it comes to what you think is deallocation of resource. For example, `delete` doesn't usually return the memory to OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object ***o*** to be asynchronously destroyed with respect to the thread, ***T***, in which it was created cannot itself be managed via RAII, because destruction of stack-allocated objects is inherently synchronous.  If ***o*** is managed via the RAII model then thread ***T*** will execute its destructor when the innermost block containing its declaration terminates, until the destructor terminates.

If you do not want to occupy ***T*** with releasing ***o***'s resources (yet ensure that they are in fact released), then you must delegate the resource release to another thread.  You can do that either

- directly, by creating ***o*** dynamically with `new` and dispatching the corresponding `free` asynchronously (e.g. via `std::async`), or
- indirectly with RAII, by having ***o***'s destructor dispatch the resource cleanup for separate asynchronous release (again, via `std::async` or similar).

The latter is indirect because it requires a separate object or objects to represent the resource(s) being cleaned up until the cleanup is complete -- especially so if there are callbacks involved or similar.  You face the same issue with these objects that you do with ***o*** itself.  There is nothing inherently wrong with this indirection, by the way.  RAII still provides the benefits it usually does.

Comment: is my proposed solution OK?

Comment: No it is not, @КириллВолков.  The lifetime of the `res` member of a `ResourceWrapper` ends when the host `ResourceWrapper`'s destructor terminates.  At that time, all extant pointers to it become invalid.  This is an example of what I mean when I say "You face the same issue with these objects that you do with ***o*** itself."  It you want `res`'s to be created by the wrapper yet have its lifetime decoupled from that of the wrapper, then you must allocate it dynamically.

Comment: No. When I call close, shared_from this is saved to lambda capture

Comment: You say "I should allocate it dynamically" - if I use shared pointer it actually assumes that the object is dynamically allocated

Comment: Sorry, @КириллВолков, yes.  `res` is a `shared_ptr`, so supposing that it actually points to a dynamically allocated `Resource`, your approach works.  It is an example of the RAII alternative this answer describes.  Also, `shared_ptr` does assume that the resource is dynamically allocated, but you can nevertheless create `shared_ptr`s to other objects.  Of course, doing so is a recipe for disaster in its own right.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two classes: `AcquirableResource` and `AcquiredResource`. You first create the `AcquirableResource` instance, which outlasts close (might even be used to reopen); then you have `AcquiredResource` from `AcquirableResource` which is the opened resource. This is fully RAII.

```
// define the AcquirableResource and AcquiredResource

int main() {
    AcquirableResource ares("filename.txt");
    // ... your code here ...
    {
        auto res(ares); // open
        if (!res) { /* error handler */ }

        // ... your code here ...

        // res goes out of scope, signals ares
        // ares closes file (can be async)
    }
    // ares is still valid here

    // ... your code here ...

    // ares goes out of scope, dtor close in sync
}
```

Comment: I am not the downvoter :) But is actually AcquirableResource the wrapper of the AcquiredResource - so it is similar to the solution that I have proposed in my question?

Comment: Not my downvote, but it's unclear to me how this solves what I take to be the OP's problem, which is essentially that they want asynchronous destruction of the object in question (maybe the destruction process is costly), which must complete before its storage is reclaimed.

Comment: @КириллВолков It's not just a wrapper. It's a distinct type. `AcquirableResource` represent a class that can have e.g. file size, status of operation, error codes. Whereas `AcquiredResource` represents the opened file. Yes, it's similar but not identical, the difference is that we have two types here. By having 2 distinct types, life cycle management is solved via RAII.

Comment: @JohnBollinger OP asked for a way to have both 1. RAII and 2. async close. I gave a high-level description of an interface for that, via 2 types: one to represent the file, one to represent the opened file. File is opened on construction of latter, closing file starts on dtor of latter; but it's essentially the former that closes the file.

Comment: @lorro what do you mean by // ares is still valid here - yes, this object is still exists but it has been requested to close

Comment: @КириллВолков When `res` is destructed, it signals `ares` that file should be closed (this function is not accessible outside). Then `ares` can instruct the OS to start closing the file in the background (or do it on another thread, etc.). During that time, your code might run and `ares` is accessible - e.g., you can pool the status of closing the file, the file size, bytes written (if exposed by OS - useful for old pendrives), etc.

Comment: @lorro, yes, and inasmuch as the `AcquirableResource` manages release of the resources involved, that must complete before that object's destructor completes. Thus, resource management must be synchronous with respect to that object.  Execution of the thread that acquires the resources must synchronize with resource release at or before that point.  This is not asynchronous in the sense I take the OP to mean.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You always have _something_ holding the object; I just made it explicit by naming it. If you don't care about status, etc, you can allocate it on the heap via `new AcquirableResource` and never delete it. The memory occupied by it then will be `free`'d when the program exists.